# Has Vandal Savage ever been incinerated, vaporized, etc.?

Tags: dc

DC Comics' villain [**Vandal Savage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandal_Savage) is immortal and has come back from all kinds of nastiness, including falling into orbit and being burnt down to just bone. Savage's immortality is not strictly from a healing factor like Wolverine, though - it's more like a reset switch when he dies. However, this brings up an interesting question:

**Has Vandal Savage ever been seen regenerating from complete incineration, or otherwise from seemingly nothing?**

Examples would be any comic issue or DC property (animated shows, etc.) where Savage is shown to survive complete incineration into ash, total disintegration, falling into a sun, etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can determine, given the inherent difficulty of proving a negative, **no**. In the comics, as reported by the very [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandal_Savage) you provide in your question:

> ...Savage is still vulnerable to external damage, meaning that if stabbed, burned, or dismembered, Savage’s body would be incapable of healing from the damage at anything more than a regular human rate.

Further,

> Savage will possibly meet his end after he has lived to the year 85,271 A.D. (as seen in the DC One Million storyline), when he is sent back in time to 20th century Montevideo, Uruguay, by a pair of doctored time traveling gauntlets, seconds before it is obliterated by a Rocket Red armorsuit carrying a huge nuclear payload, an action that was, ironically, ordered by Savage himself...

The continuity containing DC One Million persisted for several more years before it was rebooted, and no future Vandal Savage coalesced from the nuclear dust in that time.

It seems that the DCAU version of Savage was the main, if not only, version to have the self-repair power, and the DCAU, at least, didn't thoroughly obliterate him.